# How to change an environment into newcommand?

Tags: macros, environments, comments, texdef

Suppose that I want to create a new command named *step*, which functionally add **Step 1.**, **Step 2.**, and so on in the proof. This can be done by:

```
\newcounter{stepnum}
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{stepnum}\textbf{Step \arabic{stepnum}}.}
```

The problem is, which will not automatically start a newline at the end of each **step**, but this can be fixed by:

```
\newcounter{stepnum}
\newenvironment{step}{\stepcounter{stepnum}\textbf{Step \arabic{stepnum}}.}{\par}
```

I "hate" to write **\begin{step}** and **\end{step}** each time, clearly the command **\step** is more simple, but in the later case **\step** will not add a **par** at the end of line.

How can I fix this?

Comment: consider adding `\par` at the beginning of the expansion of the command.  if it's in vertical mode, it should make no difference; if in horizontal mode, it will have the desired effect.  assuming you're using an environment for `proof`, that should take care of the end of the group.

Comment: It works! But why the "beginning" par are working at the "end" of line? even through I have more than one paragraph in a step?

Comment: TOO Long, I can't get the point, why this related?

Comment: @barbarabeeton's suggestion is very nice, otherwise you could define your command with an argument: `\newcommand{\step}[1]{\stepcounter{stepnum}\textbf{Step \arabic{stepnum}}. #1\par}`  


`\step{This is the first step}\step{This is the second step}` should work.

Comment: If you are automatically enumerating something it is better to use `\refstepcounter` rather than `\stepcounter` then you can use `label`/`\ref`. Also it's normally better to use a list environment definition: your definition is essentially the definition of `\item` but the standard definition goes to a lot of trouble to get `\par` handling right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thus a good advise!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd do it differently:

```
\newcounter{stepnum}
\newenvironment{steps}
  {\setcounter{stepnum}{0}}
  {\par}
\newcommand{\step}{%
  \par
  \refstepcounter{stepnum}%
  \textbf{Step \arabic{stepnum}}.\enspace\ignorespaces
}
```

Thus you can do

```
\begin{steps}
\step This is the first
\step And the second

\step Third
\end{steps}
```

The blank line is optional.

However, using `enumitem` is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps,1]{
  leftmargin=*,
  label=\textbf{Step \arabic*}.,
  ref=Step~\arabic*,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{steps}
\item This is the first
\item And the second

\item Third
\end{steps}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can customize the list in many ways.